# Is there a way to set the console window to a fixed max/min value

Tags: c#, console, max, min

Currently I'm determining the position of certain words in the console and after entering the Enter key I always place the cursor on the next word, but I have the problem that if I change the size of the window my stored word coordinates are no longer correct.

```
foreach (var item in splittedTxt)
            {
                if (wordToFind == item)
                {
                    var cursorPositionTop = Console.CursorTop;
                    var cursorPositionLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    wordFound = true;


                    foundWordPositions.Add(new CursorPosition(cursorPositionTop, cursorPositionLeft));
                }
                Console.Write(item);
                if (wordFound) // reset color
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    wordFound = false;


                }

                Console.Write(" ");
            }

//Sets the cursor to my found results
foreach (var item in foundWordPositions)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(item.CursorLeftPosition, item.CursorTopPosition);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be abit of a hacky way to achieve what you are looking for but im not sure of any other way how to achieve this:

```
  private void CheckAndResetWindowSize(){
      if(Console.WindowHeight != 200|| Console.WindowWidth != 400) {
          Console.SetWindowSize(400, 200);
      }
  }
```

this would allow users to be able to edit the size of the window but it will auto resize back to what it should be.

let me know if this would help.

Comment: I theoretically need an event to execute this methdode and the console has no events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DeleteMenu()` function from user32-API to disable resizing of you console window. Check [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.DeleteMenu) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-deletemenu) link on how to use it. A complete solution to your problem can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1aa43c6c-71b9-42d4-aa00-60058a85f0eb/c-console-window-disable-resize?forum=csharpgeneral).